# slice on array U32 on chrome

Tags: javascript

Im using this library "Zen Photon Garden" and I have some problem (if i resize the canvas) on chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: this.Z32.slice is not a function rayworker-asm.js:461"

```
 this.U32.set(this.Z32.slice(0, l >> 2), begin >> 2);
```

I discovered that slice, in this case, its only supported by firefox, how can I fix it?

```
this.heap = new ArrayBuffer(0x800000);
this.F32 = new Float32Array(this.heap);
this.U32 = new Uint32Array(this.heap);
this.zeroes = new ArrayBuffer(0x10000);
this.Z32 = new Uint32Array(this.zeroes);
```

Comment: something like `Array.prototype.slice.call(this.Z32, 0, l >> 2)`?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined"

Comment: what you try? in sample `slice` from `Array.prototype` it can't be _undefined_

Comment: I try this.Z32.prototype.slice and this.Z32.prototype.slice.call.
btw its here http://rocketmind.it/prova/merge/prova.html

Comment: but as you see i not use `this.Z32` - because it object, and have not `prototype` property, you should check variant that i provide  _as is_: `Array.prototype.slice.call(this.Z32, 0, l >> 2)`

Comment: so, `rayworker-asm.js` is your own file? or a some third-party library?

Comment: library (Zen Photon Garden), now i don't have errors, but it still not working. btw ty!

Comment: _not working_ you mean _do nothing_? or do something wrong?

Comment: in your html i see error that raise many times: `this.U32.set(counts, src >> 2);` so seems like somewhere error with calculation